# How To Replace Cells With Specific Value In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If [E2] <> [G1] Then Range("H9:H44").Value = "Pendente"
End Sub
```

I need to include in the initial check whether the cells to be changed have a specific value.

I tried the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If [E2] <> [G1] And Range("H9:H44").Value = "Paga" Then Range("H9:H44").Value = "Pendente"
End Sub
```

That is, I need it to change only the cells that have the value "Paga" in that column.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I need it to change only the cells that have the value "Paga" in that column.

Use `.Replace` so that it can replace all text in one go.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If [E2] <> [G1] Then
        Range("H9:H44").Replace What:="Paga", Replacement:="Pendente", LookAt:=xlWhole
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
    With Sheet1 'Change as needed
        If .Cells(2, 5).Value <> .Cells(1, 7).Value Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 9 To 44
                If .Cells(i, 8).Value = "Paga" Then
                    .Cells(i, 8).Value = "Pendente"
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, obviously change SheetName to your sheetname

```
For i = 9 to 44
x= Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(2,5)
y= Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(1,7)
z= Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(i,8)
If x<>y and z="Paga" then Worksheets("SheetName").Cells(i,8)="Pendente"
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can put this into a button (button below is called Replace) or use a macro

```
Private Sub Replace_Click()
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("H9:H44")

    If c.Value = "Paga" Then

     c.Value = "Pendente"

    End If

  Next c
End Sub
```

> hope this helped